# Can you do a select top in a case inside a subquery with a top one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to perform a select statement inside a subquery that looks for the TOP 1, but only if the original result is Null. This is what I Have so far:

```
,(select TOP 1 Dimension from CUSTINVOICETRANS WHERE invoiceID= #TempCMs.INVOICEID AND [Inv Amt] = LINEAMOUNT
    (CASE
        WHEN DIMENSION IS NULL THEN
            select TOP 1 Dimension from LEDGERTRANS WHERE ledgertrans.voucher = #TempCms.INVOICEID and ABS([Inv Amt])= AMOUNTMST
    END)
) AS 'Department'
```

but i keep getting the following error message

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 69
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 73
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I have no idea how to get past it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a literal implementation of what you're trying to achieve, you can try

```
,ISNULL((select TOP 1 Dimension from CUSTINVOICETRANS 
         WHERE invoiceID= #TempCMs.INVOICEID AND [Inv Amt] = LINEAMOUNT)
        , (select TOP 1 Dimension from LEDGERTRANS 
           WHERE ledgertrans.voucher = #TempCms.INVOICEID and ABS([Inv Amt])= AMOUNTMST))
  AS 'Department'
```

Comment: I have never seen such a syntax before which begins with comma. Can this query work on its own or does something have to be added to it ? Can you explain how this works ? Thank you.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I'm replacing the portion of the poster's query that they gave in their question. It is just one of several items in the select list of a larger select query (that was omitted by the poster).